# Dimen value confusion in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, dpi, dimension, screen-density

I have the requirement like this

For Width:
**sw0-320**: 100dp,

**sw321-** : 200dp

Where should i put this values?

In **values** folder: 100dp or 200dp,

In **values-w320dp** folder: 100dp or 200dp,

Confused here! Studied some doc but didn’t understand the fact here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android finds the most specific resource it can for the device it's running on first.

This means if you place something in `values-sw320dp` and you are running a device with a smallest width of 320dp or more, it will look here first. If it can't find the resource in that folder, it will look in the base `values` folder. If you are running a device with a smallest width of 319dp, it will *not* look in `values-sw320dp` for a resource.

Comment: Thank you, understood the fact from your comment

Answer (score 2):

The data in the `values-sw320dp` or `values-w320dp` folders will be used if the device has a smallest width or available width of 320dp or more, otherwise the data in the `values` folder will be used. So, in this case you need to put 100dp in the `values` folder and 200dp in `values-sw320dp` or `values-w320dp`. The question says the requirement is about `sw` (smallest width) but then it uses the available width (`w`) qualifier in the folder name, so it's not clear which one you'll need.

The documentation for this is in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources and there you can check the `smallestWidth` (`sw<N>dp`) and `availableWidth` (`w<N>dp`) qualifiers.